# How to Read & Update the data in JSON using AngularJs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to Angular js I don't no how to get & Update the value using JSON. Still I tried to get the data from JSON.

But it was not working here is the code.

```
        {    
        $http.get('json/data.json').success (function(data){
         $scope.myData = data;
        });
    }
```

Here is the Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/odco67md/1/)

Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: In your fiddle I am getting this : 2Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: use this --//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js and this example work on Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read about Angularjs Resource in this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Then create a service factory which is the best way to ensure re-usability of code: Change the urls to your url and `Id` is an example for passing parameters.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('resourceBase', function($resource) {

  return {

    getData: function() {

      return $resource('http://dsd:8080/getdata(:Id)', {
        Id: '@id'
      });
    },
    postData: function() {

      return $resource('http://dsd:8080/postdata');

    },
    updataData: function() {
      return $resource('http://dsd:8080/postdata(:Id)', {
        Id: '@id'
      }, {
        "update": {
          method: "PUT"
        }
      });


    }

  }

});
```

Notice that I included 'ngResource' in angular.module
Then in controller you just use these services

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', 'resourceBase',
  function($scope, resourceBase) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.Id = 1;

    $scope.GetData = function() {


      resourceBase.getData().get({
        Id: $scope.Id
      })
        .$promise.then(
          function(response) {

            alert(response);

          },
          function(error) {
            console.log("It was broken !");
            alert("Change Get URL to your one");

          });


    }
    $scope.PostData = function() {

      resourceBase.postData().save($scope.Id)
        .$promise.then(
          function(response) {
            console.log("Posted");


          },
          function(error) {
            console.log(" Not Posted");
            alert("Change Get URL to your one");

          });

    }
    $scope.UpdateData = function() {

      resourceBase.updataData().update({
        Id: $scope.Id
      }, $scope.Id)
        .$promise.then(
          function(response) {
            console.log("Uddated");


          },
          function(error) {
            console.log(" Not Uddated");
            alert("Change Get URL to your one");

          });

    }

  }
]);
```

Here is Plunker [**Link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D3tIPkLnahONMAKBESFm?p=preview)